# React native image upload to server using RNCamera gives network error

Tags: react-native

i am using react-native-camera to take picture in react native but when sending image to backend it gives network error i have used axios post,
i am getting this captured image path in console
Path of image: file:///data/user/0/com.rnapp/cache/Camera/0d33d840-af31-4375-bd30-515c1a257ea3.jpg

but when uploading/sending image to backend using axios post it give
[Error: Network Error]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to read file first then try to upload. Please specify more details about how you are doing. Im using `rn-fetch-blob` to do this. Assuming `file` contains your file captured from Camera, below will be the code.

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch('PUT', 'url', {
            'Content-Type': 'content type of your document',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }, RNFetchBlob.wrap(file.filepath)).then(() => {}, () => {})
```

Comment: i am to using RNFetchBlob but in this case i get error as path.startsWith is not a function